# Why do the official docker images build it's software from source rather than from alpine's packages?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I had the following dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.7
RUN apk add --update php7-gd
...
```

However when running this, it complained it couldn't find the php-gd extension. I then instead changed the dockerfile to:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk add --update --no-cache php7 php7-gd
...
```

Which then worked. So I'm guessing it's do with the way php is built.

None the less I find this behavior a bit intuitive. **What is the purpose on basing the image on alpine in this case? Why not use alpine's packages instead?**

Note, I am not asking how to solve this particular problem - (which is already answered here https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/7aeed6ad70a0ccdce57d42e4a152fa0dfbedbbc4/php/README.md#how-to-install-more-php-extensions).